# C++ | duda de tema sobre rangos

Tags: c++, c

Espero que me puedan ayudar con información para resolver este tipo de problema.
No me dieron título de tema ni nada por el estilo, solo que tratara de resolverlo.

El problema consiste en solicitar x, numero inicial, x numero final
y despues sumar desde el numero inicial hasta el numero inicial.

```
printf("Introduce el numero inicial");
scanf("%d",&numeroinicial);
printf("Introduce el numero final");
scanf("%d",&numerofinal);
```

Si ingreso como numero inicial 4 y numero final 10
el programa debe hacer la suma de 4+5+6+7+8+9+10

Quise resolverlo con un ciclo for pero no se como indicar la suma del rango.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías compartir lo que has hecho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para sumar todos los números entre dos valores basta con multiplicar la cantidad de valores entre ambos números por la suma del primero y el último y dividir entre dos:

[image]

Por lo tanto, la suma de todos los números entre 4 y 10 es:

```
int números = (7 * (4 + 10)) / 2;
```

#### A tener en cuenta.

- `printf` y `scanf` son las funciones de lectura de consola de C, en C++ se usan los objetos *stream*: [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) y [`std::cin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

#### Propuesta.

```
int main()
{
    int numeroinicial, numerofinal;

    std::cout << "Introduce el numero inicial";
    std::cin >> numeroinicial;

    std::cout << "Introduce el numero final";
    std::cin >> numerofinal;

    std::cout << "La suma de los valores entre " << numeroinicial
              << " y " << numerofinal
              << " es " << ((numerofinal - numeroinicial + 1) * (numeroinicial + numerofinal)) / 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que el código anterior asume que `numeroinicial` será menor que `numerofinal`.

Si en lugar de aritméticamente lo quieres hacer cíclicamente, puedes usar un bucle `for`:

```
int main()
{
    int numeroinicial, numerofinal;

    std::cout << "Introduce el numero inicial";
    std::cin >> numeroinicial;

    std::cout << "Introduce el numero final";
    std::cin >> numerofinal;

    int suma{};
    for (int valor = numeroinicial; valor < numerofinal; ++valor)
        suma += valor;

    std::cout << "La suma de los valores entre " << numeroinicial
              << " y " << numerofinal
              << " es " << suma;

    return 0;
}
```

También puedes generar ([`std::generate` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)) una colección de números dentro del rango y acumularlos ([`std::accumulate` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)):

```
int main()
{
    int numeroinicial, numerofinal;

    std::cout << "Introduce el numero inicial";
    std::cin >> numeroinicial;

    std::cout << "Introduce el numero final";
    std::cin >> numerofinal;

    std::vector valores(numerofinal - numeroinicial + 1);
    std::generate(valores.begin(), valores.end(), [i = b]() mutable { return i++; });

    std::cout << "La suma de los valores entre " << numeroinicial
              << " y " << numerofinal
              << " es " << std::accumulate(valores.begin(), valores.end(), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me sirvió muchisimo tu explicación, existe alguna forma para ponerme en contacto contigo? Gracias!

Comment: Estoy disponible en el sitio de lunes a viernes entre las 7 y las 17. Siéntete libre de preguntar (a mi y a cualquiera) sobre C++ y responderemos tan bien como sepamos :)

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo así:

```
//Declaración de variables

int NumInicial = 0, NumFinal = 0, contador = 1;
int Operacion = 0, Operacion2 = 0, SumaTotal = 0;
int Dato = 0;

cout<<"Ingrese Numero Inicial"<<endl;
cin>>NumInicial;
cout<<"Ingrese Numero Final"<<endl;
cin>>NumFinal;
//Guardamos el numero inicial
Dato = NumInicial;
for(int i=NumInicial;i<NumFinal;i++){

    Operacion = i + contador; //Operacion es igual 4 + 1, al volverse a repetir ya seria 4 + 2 y así sucesivamente.

    Operacion2 = Dato + Operacion; //Operacion2 es igual a 4 + 5, al volverse a repetir ya seria 9 + 6 y así sucesivamente.

    SumaTotal = Operacion2; //Aqui SumaTotal toma el resultado para luego mostrarlo.

    Dato = SumaTotal; //La variable Dato toma la suma actual para luego ir sumandole los demás números hasta el NumFinal.

    cout<<"Total:"<<SumaTotal<<endl;

}
```

Comment: por favor añade una explicación a tu código, pues respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad toda vez que no explicas para que sirve o como funciona este script

Comment: Eso estaba haciendo, por favor retira el negativo, ya agregue la explicación.

Comment: el negativo yo no te lo puse y precisamente previendo esa situación fue que te comento lo de la explicación

Comment: ¡Pero si este código es complicadísimo! :O se puede hacer con una sola variable de acumulación: `int resultado{};  for (int i = inicio; i <= fin; ++i) resultado += i;`

Answer (score 0):

En el bucle for, la primera instancia, declara una variable 'i', e iguala esta a la variable inicial, en la segunda, la pon que se realice el bucle mientras 'i' sea menor o igual al numero final, y en la tercera instancia, pon el operador i++, que hará que al final del bucle se le sume 1 a la variable indicada (i)

```
for(i=variableNumInicial, i<=variableNumFinal, i++){
código para la suma
}
```

Recuerda establecer una variable para ir guardando el valor de cada suma a la que sumar el nuevo numero.

Mucha suerte ;)

Comment: Sí eso lo tengo claro el problema lo tengo en el código para la suma, como puedo contar los numeros para luego sumarlos? 
Me refiero a como sabré que números se sumarán si pueden ser aleatorios

Comment: a la variable variableNumInicial le asignas el numero que te proporcionaron en printf("Introduce el numero inicial"); y variableNumFinal le asignas el numero que te den en printf("Introduce el numero final");

Answer (score 0):

He estado leyendo las respuestas y he encontrado una forma más sencilla de hacer este ejercicio:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int numInicial, numFinal, suma = 0;

    cout << "Introduce el numero inicial: ";
    cin >> numInicial;

    cout << "Final: ";
    cin >> numFinal;

    for (int i = numInicial; i <= numFinal; i++){

        suma += i;

    }

    cout << suma << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

El programa te pedirá introducir el valor para **numInicial** y **numFinal**.

Lo que he hecho ha sido declarar tres variables: `int numInicial;` (almacenará el número inicial), `int numFinal;` (almacenará el número final) y `suma = 0;` (se encargará de almacenar la suma de los números).

En el bucle **for**, he igualado la variable **i** a **numInicial**: `int i = numInicial;`. Con esto queremos que el bucle comience con el primer número que hayamos introducido para empezar la serie. La condición del bucle es que la variable **i** sea menor o igual a **numFinal**, para poder salir del bucle al pasarnos del número final. Dentro del bucle, he ido actualizando la variable **suma**, sumándole el valor de **i**: `suma += i;`.

Al salir del bucle, el programa muestra el valor de la suma.

Espero que te haya sido útil y un saludo.